# how to pull a specific local commit by your teammate in his repo to your working repo

Tags: git, commit, pull

Can I pull one specific local commit(not pushed to central repo) from my teammate's local repository to mine??

I am only interested to take the changes with that particular commit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+single+commit

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you and your teammate are using git, if he has a local commit that he wants to share with you, he can use `git push --follow-tags`. This will push the commit and all its ancestors to your repository, so make sure you're okay with that before running the command.

Comment: But I only need the changes in one particular commit, not the changes up to and including that commit

Comment: Try to use "git cherry-pick <local_commit_hash>"